# AWS Quicksight: Disable excel downloads

Tags: amazon-quicksight

AWS Quicksight has an option to export reports over excel and csv. Excel has limitation that only upto 40k rows can be downloaded. If the data is more than that it gets truncated and gives a wrong message to user if he/she don't know it's truncated. Where as csv has much more limit (1 million rows).

So I'm thinking to disable excel download option and to keep only csv download enabled. I checked multiple options. But I can see only option to enable/disable csv downloads.

Is there a way I can disable excel downloads?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that is possible.  Checking the [API Documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/quicksight.html#QuickSight.Client.create_dashboard) there is a ExportToCSVOption option, but no excel option documented.